# to_timesamp converting month to different month

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, to-timestamp

Any idea why snowflake to_timestamp is converting February month to January?

```
    SELECT to_timestamp(to_char('2022-02-02 08:01:29 AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MM:SS AM');
    -- 2022-01-02 08:00:29.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MM` represent month when you convert to char , you should use `MI` for minute in snowflake, I assume the issue comes from there :

```
SELECT to_timestamp(to_char('2022-02-02 08:01:29 AM','YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM'));
```